# Something went wrong in downloading and extracting project files Invalid response body ~blah~ expo-template-bare-minimum: EACCES: permission denied

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm, expo

So I'm having trouble initializing expo project, everything works, I'm using `nvm` at `node v14.16.1 (npm v7.11.2)`.

```sh
expo init Doorgy
✔ Choose a template: › minimal               bare and minimal, just the essentials to get you started
✖ Something went wrong in downloading and extracting the project files.
Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-bare-minimum: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/anthonykung/.expo/template-cache/tmp/0d1e04ab'
FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/expo-template-bare-minimum: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/anthonykung/.expo/template-cache/tmp/0d1e04ab'
    at /home/anthonykung/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/body.js:162:15
    at extractTemplateAppAsync (/home/anthonykung/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/utils/extractTemplateAppAsync.ts:118:3)
    at extractAndPrepareTemplateAppAsync (/home/anthonykung/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/utils/extractTemplateAppAsync.ts:82:3)
    at action (/home/anthonykung/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/init.ts:270:19)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/home/anthonykung/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:350:7)
```

It kept throwing me that error no matter what I did, I try fixing `npm`, I tried fixing `nvm`, using different versions, uninstalling, messing with registries, pretty much everything I can find but it just kept showing this annoying error...

Here's a very long list of what I did:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g expo-cli
sudo npm install -g expo-cli
node -v
sudo apt-get update
npm cache verify
sudo expo init Doorgy
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
vi ~/.npmrc
npm outdated -g
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
npm install -g expo-cli
expo init Doorgy
~/.npm-global
mkdir ~/.npm-global
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
npm config delete prefix
expo init Doorgy
npm config set prefix $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v14.16.1
expo init Doorgy
npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
vi ~/.profile 
source ~/.profile
npm i -g expo-cli
expo init Doorgy
nvm use default 
npm i -g expo-cli
expo init Doorgy
npm config delete prefix
npm i -g expo-cli
npm cache verify
sudo npm i -g expo-cli
npm i -g expo-cli
expo init Doorgy
nvm use default 
sudo npm i -g expo-cli
expo init Doorgy
npm cache clean
cd
ls
ls -al
cd dev/DoorgyApp/
expo init Doorgy
npx expo init Doorgy
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli
expo init Doorgy
npm config set strict-ssl false
expo init Doorgy
npm config set strict-ssl true
npm uninstall expo-cli
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
nvm use default
cp ~/.npmrc ~/.old-npmrc
vi ~/.npmrc
expo init Doorgy
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
sudo npm uninstall -g expo-cli
```

And none of them works so I did something random and it works... see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did everything out there including the followings:

```
npm cache verify
```

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g expo-cli
```

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

But they all didn't work so I decided to uninstall expo-cli and reinstall. So I do

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli
```

To my surprise, it survived and I can still use `expo init`, so I naturally add sudo to it and guess what it's still there. Now very frustrated I try to delete every place that it exists starting from my home directory.

```
rm -rf /home/anthonykung/.expo/
rm: cannot remove '/home/anthonykung/.expo/template-cache/index-v5/d6/46/41a4d65191fd14edff849b1a5474a12dec9a503a4065b3d9fcfc568a5a3d': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/anthonykung/.expo/template-cache/index-v5/70/6f/218f4428aaa14899cf226ad3dbf086f32f36d36b64c6e5c3423b10488c8e': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/anthonykung/.expo/template-cache/content-v2/sha512/6d/28/efad7e78f4322111b65ccfd0dbcf763fc05cf73cc83edd751dc168af2e09437205de510f66ac3bc3289aeee7bd594cd3a8a9661e76fcd2ff263fd8dc4d11': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/anthonykung/.expo/template-cache/content-v2/sha512/23/26/522f178834febb149d5f9085ab51a65d6c43cac596a90ac4234151594e5248f32c03efb71870cd71e355781bdb0a80907f8bcac53d31ca8c34ec0897167d': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/home/anthonykung/.expo/template-cache/tmp': Permission denied
```

```
sudo rm -rf /home/anthonykung/.expo/
```

But there something came to mind... `Permission denied` that sounds like the error expo is yelling about! So I did `expo init` again with high hope and...

```
✔ Choose a template: › minimal               bare and minimal, just the essentials to get you started
✔ Downloaded and extracted project files.
 Using npm to install packages.
✔ Installed JavaScript dependencies.
✔ Skipped installing CocoaPods because operating system is not on macOS.

✅ Your project is ready!

To run your project, navigate to the directory and run one of the following npm commands.

- cd Doorgy
- npm run android
- npm run ios # you need to use macOS to build the iOS project - use managed workflow if you need to do iOS development without a Mac
- npm run web

 You can also open up the projects in the ios and android directories with their respective IDEs.
 expo-updates (​https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-updates/README.md​) has been installed in your project. Before you do a release build, you'll need to configure a few values in Expo.plist and AndroidManifest.xml in order for updates to work.
```

IT WORKS!!! HOLY COW THAT WORKS!!!

Before I deleted it I check the permission and owner of the `~/.expo` directory and it shows the right permission with the right owner... It never occurred to me that something inside was broken and removing them works. I'm sure this is just a rare thing that almost never happened to anyone else (I've never encountered this until now so...) but if it does happen to somebody I hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Just use Sudo before.

"sudo init expo Doorgy"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. What I did to fix this is, I uninstalled node from the snap packages and I reinstalled it from their website.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've ever had this error before and I run the following terminal comands to solve. (The goal is to uninstall completly the current nodejs, install NodeSource PPA, then install nodejs from that)

1. `sudo apt purge nodejs`
2. `sudo apt autoremove`
3. `sudo apt clean`
4. `cd ~`
5. `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x -o /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh`
6. `nano /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh (Just to see what was in the .sh file)`
7. `sudo bash /tmp/nodesource_setup.sh (this run the nodesource .sh file)`
8. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
9. `sudo apt install -f nodejs`

Answer (score 0):

I just had to add sudo command and it worked

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using `Default` option for `How would you like to start`, choose `Template from expo/examples: https://github.com/expo/examples`, it worked for me

Comment: I did that, and I still got this useless error message.